# Security Exception when hosting mvc 5 website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

i have create mvc 5 application but when i host app into server i get the below error:

[image]

i tried set trust level but it not solved my problem:

```
<trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>
```

OR

```
<securityPolicy>
    <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/>
</securityPolicy>
```

Comment: From the error message, it seems it is not permission issue, but it is your code issue. Could you please check it again?

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by two ways. 
1 - Add following code in WebConfig 
`<system.web>
    <trust level="Full" />
</system.web>`

Comment: _This can be done by two ways_. Where's the second way?